# Data table with vertical heading d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3 and html. From the following code, I understand how to create a table with horizontal heading in d3. Kindly tell me how to create a table with D3 having vertical headings.

```
function tabulate(data, columns) {
    var table = d3.select("body").append("table")
            .attr("style", "margin-left: 250px"),
        thead = table.append("thead"),
        tbody = table.append("tbody");

    // append the header row
    thead.append("tr")
        .selectAll("th")
        .data(columns)
        .enter()
        .append("th")
            .text(function(column) { return column; });

    // create a row for each object in the data
    var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("tr");

    // create a cell in each row for each column
    var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
        .data(function(row) {
            return columns.map(function(column) {
                return {column: column, value: row[column]};
            });
        })
        .enter()
        .append("td")
        .attr("style", "font-family: Courier")
            .html(function(d) { return d.value; });

    return table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Table elements don't have vertical header elements. However, you can create some by adding in a new column to your data:

```
new column:    original columns:
vertical-head | col-1 | col-2 | col-3
row-1         | 1     | 1     | 1
row-2         | 2     | 2     | 2
row-3         | 3     | 3     | 3
```

and then styling it by adding css to those cells (whether inline in D3 or by adding classes to them).

----UPDATE----

To change the styling of the left column, you can either add css inline, or you can add a class to the left cells and change the css in your stylesheet (recommended):

JS:

```
var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(row) {
        return columns.map(function(column) {
            return {column: column, value: row[column]};
        });
    })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .attr("style", "font-family: Courier")
    .attr('class', 'horizontal-header')
    .html(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

CSS:

```
.horizontal-header {
    // add css styles here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tony..request you to give an example how to style cells of new colum in d3